# Can I compile and run a spring boot jar from inside another spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, gradle, tomcat

So quick clarifications because I have read some of the previous similar questions:

1. I'm looking to compile and run a spring boot codebase from a running spring application.
2. I'm not looking to nest or package multiple spring boot jars inside one. The second spring boot codebase is outside. Maybe even on github.

I have already looked at https://www.toptal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-application-programmatic-launch. It was super helpful, but I'm not sure how to compile and load a spring boot application.

I have an inkling that this is done at the Tomcat TomcatServletWebServerFactory level - basically the spring boot "helper" application will trigger tomcat to load the external jar and deploy. I'm not 100% sure if this is correct.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is the original problem you want to solve with this?

Comment: @JFabianMeier we are building an internal CI/CD tool for a particular industry (banking related) - where test deployments are strictly controlled and have to follow certain audit requirements. so we will be using this to build and test-deploy within controlled environments. this is not public cloud, etc. Docker is still hard to introduce here. and if we use external CI tools, i will need PCI-DSS audit of the same. this is a much cheaper/quicker/cost-effective/audit-friendly alternative

Comment: So you have an audit for spring boot, but not for Maven? Anyway, I would think about writing a bash script or a plain Java program.

Comment: we do have an audit for maven. but there are tons of approval steps required for each test deploy, which is captured in excel. and which i can productize as a spring boot application (if i can load an external jar). it seems it can using TomcatServletWebServerFactory , but i thank you for your orthogonal suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Can’t you simply build and run your secondary Spring Boot applications in *external processes* that are started from within your primary Spring Boot application?

I’ve just tried this in a very simple proof-of-concept. For this POC, I have created two dummy Spring Boot applications, one called `outer` and one called `inner`. The latter is supposed to be built and run by the former.

Here’s the directory structure (ommitting [Gradle 7.6 Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) files in each of the two Gradle projects for brevity):

```
├── inner
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── settings.gradle
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── java
│           │   └── com
│           │       └── example
│           │           └── demo
│           │               └── DemoApplication.java
│           └── resources
│               └── application.properties
└── outer
    ├── build.gradle
    ├── settings.gradle
    └── src
        └── main
            └── java
                └── com
                    └── example
                        └── demo
                            └── DemoApplication.java
```

The two `settings.gradle` files are both empty. The two `build.gradle` files have the same content, too:

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
}
```

The “inner” application is the demo applicatation from the [Spring Quickstart Guide](https://spring.io/quickstart), i.e., `inner/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java` looks as follows:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return String.format("Hello %s!", name);
    }
}
```

The `inner/src/main/resources/application.properties` file additionally contains `server.port=8081` so that its web server is run on a different port than the one of “outer”.

That leaves us with `outer/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java` which defines the following (crude) application:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

    private Process otherAppProcess = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostMapping("/run")
    public String run() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (otherAppProcess != null) {
                stop();
            }
            var processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("./gradlew", "bootRun");
            processBuilder.directory(new File("../inner"));
            otherAppProcess = processBuilder.start();
        }
        return "Done.";
    }

    @PostMapping("/stop")
    public String stop() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (otherAppProcess != null) {
                otherAppProcess.destroy();
                otherAppProcess = null;
            }
        }
        return "Ok.";
    }
}
```

You can now run `./gradlew bootRun` in `outer/` to start the “outer” Spring Boot application – a Tomcat web server. That server reacts to a POST request wich starts a Gradle build of the “inner” Spring Boot application which also runs that application (once the build is complete). For example, you can now try the following interaction:

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8081/hello
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8081 after 0 ms: Connection refused
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/run
Done.
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8081/hello
Hello World!
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/stop
Ok.
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm - I know you wanted sample Code, but I lack the time currently to try it out by myself and this here might not be a real answer - but too big for a comment:

I never done something like this before, but maybe I could throw my idea in here - if it sucks, feel free to ignore it.

I don't know if your "Main Spring Boot Project" uses the Maven Wrapper, but lets assume it does.

So let's try the following concept:

- You start your "Main" Spring Boot Application, which actually could Build and Start multiple Spring Boot Applications.
- The Main Spring Boot Application checksout X different Spring Boot Applications from GitHub / GitLab whatever (with `git clone`) in some directories of its choice. (you could do this with JGit or with **Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your git command")**  or whatever comes in your mind)
- Knowing that the Maven Wrapper exists in this folder, you could basically build the Spring Boot JAR in the **target** Folder, (or like with Gradle when you do `gradlew bootJar`)
- After the "Shell Command" did execute successfully, you could start the Spring Boot Jar by executing something like `java -jar path/to/your/mySpringBoot.jar fully.qualified.package.Application`

Does it sound conceptually somewhat you want to do? In the end, if we think about it - it is the same, when you checkout your Project manually, build the JAR and start it - ain't it?

Answer (score 1):

Taking an example from Chriki answer, I can run another spring boot app from the so called OuterApp . Inner app will run on the port number which as example can be 8081.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

public class OuterApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      
        SpringApplication.run(OuterApplication.class, args);
        
        SpringApplication innerApp = new SpringApplication(InnerApplication.class);
        innerApp.setDefaultProperties(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
            put("server.port", "8081");
        }});
        innerApp.run(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the SpringApplication.run() method to start the inner application within the main application.

```
    @SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        return args -> {
            // Start your inner application here
            SpringApplication.run(InnerApplication.class, args);
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JavaCompiler`.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> fileObjects = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays.asList("src/main/java/com/example/app2/Application.java"));
        compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, fileObjects).call();
        fileManager.close();
        
        // you can run jar file from this host application
        String[] newArgs = {"--spring.config.name=externalApp", "--spring.config.additional-location=file:/etc/externalApp/"};
        SpringApplication.run(com.example.externalApp.Application.class, newArgs);
    }
```

Also take a look at the documentation ->  [Java Compiler](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/CompilingfromMemory.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at "Maven Invoker" yet?  Not only can you do it, you can do anything that you can do with Maven.

Here is an example (it uses TestContainers, but doesn't have to) from [my github](https://github.com/dashaun/spring-boot-3-buildpacks-with-testcontainers-cloud).

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.DefaultInvocationRequest;
import org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.DefaultInvoker;
import org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.InvocationResult;
import org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.MavenInvocationException;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.util.DigestUtils;
import org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory;
import org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer;
import org.testcontainers.utility.LazyFuture;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class OCIwithTCCTest {
    private static final Future<String> IMAGE_FUTURE = new LazyFuture<>() {
        @Override
        protected String resolve() {
            // Find project's root dir
            File cwd;
            for (
                    cwd = new File(".");
                    !new File(cwd, "mvnw").isFile();
                    cwd = cwd.getParentFile()
            );

            // Make it unique per folder (for caching)
            var imageName = String.format(
                    "local/demo-%s:%s",
                    DigestUtils.md5DigestAsHex(cwd.getAbsolutePath().getBytes()),
                    System.currentTimeMillis()
            );

            var properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("spring-boot.build-image.imageName", imageName);
            properties.put("skipTests", "true");

            var request = new DefaultInvocationRequest()
                    .addShellEnvironment("DOCKER_HOST", DockerClientFactory.instance().getTransportConfig().getDockerHost().toString())
                    .setPomFile(new File(cwd, "pom.xml"))
                    .setGoals(List.of("spring-boot:build-image"))
                    .setMavenExecutable(new File(cwd, "mvnw"))
                    .setProperties(properties);

            InvocationResult invocationResult;
            try {
                invocationResult = new DefaultInvoker().execute(request);
            } catch (MavenInvocationException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            if (invocationResult.getExitCode() != 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException(invocationResult.getExecutionException());
            }

            return imageName;
        }
    };


    static final GenericContainer<?> APP = new GenericContainer<>(IMAGE_FUTURE)
            .withExposedPorts(8080);
    
    @Test
    void containerStartupTest() {
        APP.start();
    }
}
```

The dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-invoker</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This example repository builds the application into an OCI image using spring-boot:build-image and then runs a test against that image, all from within a test, using Maven Invoker.